# Which is the best way to specify "justify" for grid item in material-ui?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I have a simple Grid from the `material-UI` library. It looks like that:

```
<Grid container>
    <Grid item sm={6}>
        <SearchPanel/>
    </Grid>
    <Grid item sm={6}>
        <ItemStatusFilter/>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

I just can't understand how can I align the first grid item in the center, and the second, for example, on the right side?

UPD: I could do it with `justify-content: flex-end!important` in my `CSS` files, but I'm not sure that it's the best way.

Comment: Could you add an extra, empty <Grid> element to the beginning of the row?

Comment: @DuncanThacker Hmm, sorry, but I don't understand what do you mean?

Comment: Like `<Grid container><Grid item sm={3} /><Grid item sm={3}><SearchPanel /></Grid><Grid item sm={3}><ItemStatusFilter/></Grid></Grid>`

Comment: @DuncanThacker Nice trick, but I think there must be some other way (maybe using a `material-UI`)

Comment: There's now a `justify` prop, but I haven't checked if it was added after the question was asked.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Below is one way of doing this for v3 and v4 of Material-UI (v5 example further down).

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

import Grid from "@material-ui/core/Grid";

function App() {
  return (
    <Grid container>
      <Grid item xs={4}>
        {/* Intentionally Empty */}
      </Grid>
      <Grid container item xs={4} justify="center">
        <div>Search Panel</div>
      </Grid>
      <Grid container item xs={4} justify="flex-end">
        <div>Item Status Filter</div>
      </Grid>
    </Grid>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

This is the general idea of Duncan's comment. I have changed `sm` to `xs` just so I could verify the behavior on any size screen. In the end, Material-UI's [`Grid`](https://material-ui.com/api/grid/) just adds some convenience around the [CSS Flexbox model](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/), so to know how to do it with `Grid` you need to understand how you would do it in CSS. The main thing `Grid` adds is the easy responsive aspects of controlling the 12-column grid differently for different screen sizes.

[image: Edit y25382q6r1]

Here's an equivalent example for v5 (`justify` prop renamed to `justifyContent`):

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

import Grid from "@mui/material/Grid";

function App() {
  return (
    <Grid container>
      <Grid item xs={4}>
        {/* Intentionally Empty */}
      </Grid>
      <Grid container item xs={4} justifyContent="center">
        <div>Search Panel</div>
      </Grid>
      <Grid container item xs={4} justifyContent="flex-end">
        <div>Item Status Filter</div>
      </Grid>
    </Grid>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

[image: Edit Grid justify]

Comment: `justify` is now [`justifyContent`](https://mui.com/system/flexbox/#justify-content), and is part of the [system properties](https://mui.com/system/properties/)

Comment: @kca I've updated my answer to include a v5 example.